# We have 2015 tfs server with 8 collections to be migrated to azure devops i have tried Microsoft azure devops migration

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, migration

We have 2015 tfs server with 8 collections to be migrated to azure devops i have tried Microsoft azure devops migration tool but it is considering each collection as single organization but we want to all 8 collections under one organization each collection has different projects
Is there any way to do this i have seen Microsoft documention but unable to get any perfect solution what should i do could some please gudie me regarding this

Comment: Welcome! This doesn't seem like a programming-related question; more of a specific product's migration approach (moving from TFS to Azure DevOps). As such, this question is off-topic here. Maybe there's something related to a script that I'm not seeing? If so: it would help if you edited your question to contain specifics. Right now, it's very broad and unclear, and seems more of a documentation-request question.

Comment: Thanks David for reply this is more about migration of data from tfs server 2015 to azure devops cloud i can't find any steps to follow to migration of more than 1 collection to devops i ams struck there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's documentation is the canonical, correct answer. You aren't finding other solutions because none exist. There is no way to import multiple team project collections into a single Azure DevOps organization via any tooling whatsoever. There is no other option for a full fidelity migration; although other tools exist that can migrate some data, no tool can capture all of the data, and no tool can capture the data without loss of fidelity.

Simple put, organizations are the Azure DevOps equivalent of team project collections. Each organization represents a single collection.

Comment: And functionally there isn't much of a difference. Except for cost of extensions and licenses. But, you can setup multi-organization billing to have your licenses flow between the orgs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/billing-faq?view=azure-devops#multi-organization-billing